# Ionic: directive doesn't work in ionicModal

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

As the title, I define a directive and use it in the template of ionicModal, but it doesn't work，the console log '111' doesn't print.thks for help!
here is the code:

directive.js

```
.directive 'size_item', () ->
  restrict: 'AE'
  link: (scope, elem, attr) ->
    console.log 111
    $(elem).parents().find("div:first").addClass('active')
```

../tpls/modal/add_cart.html

```
<div class="size_item list_item" size_item>S</div>
```

controller.js

```
.controller 'ProductDetailCtrl', ['$ionicModal', '$scope', '$http',
  '$stateParams', ($ionicModal, $scope, $http, $stateParams) ->
  $scope.showCart = () ->
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl '../tpls/modal/add_cart.html',
      scope:$scope,
      animation: 'animated bounceInUp'
```

Comment: You will need to show the code and describe what *doesn't work* - we cannot see what's on your screen and cannot answer your question with the information you provided.

Comment: thks for remind , i had already update!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that the error come from the name of directive, in my code, i named it as size_item, it's not legal, no underline is allowed!